# react send data to a component to use with flask

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, flask

hi sorry im new to react dev but im trying to parse an id and a user_id from matches.js to messages.js. the messages.js should work with a flask function. when the messages component is loaded it returns the id for the user as undefined. how to i change this code so that the id is included in the url and that the user_id is sent as data.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "./matches.css";

function Matches() {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(""); // userId is the user's id that they enter
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams(); // id is the user's id that is passed in from the url

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/matches/${userId}`);
      const matchesWithIds = res.data;
      setMatches(matchesWithIds);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setUserId(e.target.value);
  };

  const getMessagesWithUser = (matchId) => {
    navigate(`/messages/${userId}`, { state: { id: id, user_id: matchId } });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Get Matches</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          User ID:
          <input type="text" value={userId} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {matches.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h2>Matches:</h2>
          <ul>
            {matches.map((match) => (
              <li
                key={match}
                className="match-card"
                onClick={() => getMessagesWithUser(match)}
              >
                {match}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Matches;
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Messages({ id, user_id }) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = useState("");
  const location = useLocation();
  const userId = location.state.user_id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMessages = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/messages/${id}`, {
          params: { user_id: user_id },
        });
        setMessages(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.response.data);
      }
    };
    getMessages();
  }, [id, user_id]);

  const handleMessageInput = (e) => {
    setMessageInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/messages`, {
        sender_id: location.state.id,
        recipient_id: location.state.user_id,
        message: messageInput,
      });
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, res.data]);
      setMessageInput("");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Messages</h1>
      <h2>Conversation with user {user_id}</h2>
      <ul>
        {messages.map((message) => (
          <li key={message._id}>
            {message.sender_id}: {message.message}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
        <label>
          Message:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={messageInput}
            onChange={handleMessageInput}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Messages;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./login/login.js";
import Matches from "./matches.js";
import Home from "./home/home.js";
import Messages from "./messages.js";

function App() {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login setUserId={setUserId} />} />
        <Route path="/matches" element={<Matches userId={userId} />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home userId={userId} />} />
        <Route path="/messages/:id" element={<Messages />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
#get messages with a user
@app.route('/messages/<string:id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_messages_with_user(id):


    required_fields = ["user_id"]
    
    if all(field in request.form for field in required_fields):
        new_user = {
            
            "user_id" : request.form["user_id"]
           
            
        }
   
    
    all_messages = messages_collection.find({
        "$or": [
            {"sender_id": id, "recipient_id": new_user['user_id']},

            {"recipient_id": id, "sender_id": new_user['user_id']},
        ]
    })
    

    message_list = []
    for msg in all_messages:
        # Convert ObjectId fields to strings
        msg['_id'] = str(msg['_id'])
        msg['sender_id'] = str(msg['sender_id'])
        msg['recipient_id'] = str(msg['recipient_id'])
        message_list.append(msg)

    return jsonify(message_list)
```

the returned url to look something like this "http://localhost:5000/messages/6442d4b8e188665ed2268783" whilest sending a user_id like 6442d4b8e188665ed2268784